# MultiPart Java Form with drop down and text input

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, joptionpane

I have a form that i want to add a Drop down selector to select around 5 different things. Example `("us" , "usrelease" , "uk" , "ukrelease")` as of now i have the user input that text

```
    public class Proxy {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception , IOException , FileNotFoundException {

    //Start of Dialog Box

    JTextField Server = new JTextField();
    JTextField Amount = new JTextField();
    JTextField Server1 = new JTextField();
    Object[] message = {
            "Server Code", Server,
            "How Many Amount", Amount,
            "How Many Servers", Server1,
    };
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, "ProxyCreator", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
```

Where I have the `object server code` I would like a drop down menu there. Where you select which one you would like to use.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a JComboBox:

```
JComboBox<String> Server = new JComboBox<>(
    new String[] { "us", "usrelease", "uk", "ukrelease" });
```

You can access the user's response and the selected/entered values  from the JComboBox and JTextField instances:

```
final int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, "ProxyCreator", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
    System.out.println("Server code: " + Server.getSelectedItem());
    System.out.println("Amount: " + Amount.getText());
}
```

Comment: @Laws Thank you so much, that worked but how would i get the text of which one they chose? write now its printing out  `javax.swing.JComboBox[,0,19,195x25,invalid,layout=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalComboBoxUI$MetalComboBoxLayoutManager,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=328,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,isEditable=false,lightWeightPopupEnabled=true,maximumRowCount=8,selectedItemReminder=usrelease]`

Comment: I updated my answer with information on how to do that.